# Update Fails Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2022 (64-bit) - Preview Version 17.3.0 Preview 5.0 to 6.0

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I am having a problem updating the version mentioned above of the visual studio with the below error message displayed:

[image]

> Visual Studio Installer Sorry, something went wrong Error: Visual
> Studio Installer The dependent package of
> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Product.Enterprise,version=17.3.32721.290,chip=x64,
> productarch=x64' cannot be found:
> Component.05D8FE2B-55EC-4A28-8865-C2570F30A1C9, version=2.0.

I've encountered problems with updating Live Share Extension after successfully updating to 17.3.0 Preview 5.0.

Now I am stuck and looking forward to availing of the community lead!

Answer (score 1):

I had also an issue with updating VS2022.

This helped for me:

1. Download a new copy of the VisualStudioSetup.exe: https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
2. Start the VisualStudioSetup.exe and update

Comment: tanx. work for me